# 1 SSL Cert for Multiple Dynamic Elastic Beanstalk Environments

Tags: ssl, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm basically trying to setup review apps where our CI spins up a review app such as `review-app-<tag>.review.ourdomain.com` based on push to a git branch.

Our CI spins up a new elastic beanstalk environment per review app. I currently have a wildcard SSL cert hooked up to our domain, which works properly.

Now, I need to figure out how to get https to work for our review apps. One solution would be to leverage Cloudflare's API to add DNS records that point `review-app-<tag>.review` to the appropriate elastic beanstalk instance's load balancer. However, DNS takes a while to propagate sometimes so it's not a great solution especially for CI workflows.

How can I get this to work without modifying DNS records? Is there a hack that could be put in place by modifying our Nginx config or using a Shared Application Load Balancer?